# Memory fault(coredump) in SQL query

Tags: c++, oracle, c++11, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to read a single row from database:

This statement is working fine

```
stmt = conn->createStatement("SELECT * from Customer");
rs = stmt->executeQuery();
```

While this is showing `Memory fault(coredump)`

```
 stmt->setSQL("SELECT * from :1");
 stmt->setString(1,"Customer");
 rs = stmt->executeQuery();
```

Comment: Placeholders can only be used for places where expressions are allowed in queries, they can't be used for table names, column names.

Comment: Thanks... but this is also showing error
`stmt->setSQL("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CUSTOMER_TYPE like :1");
stmt->setString(1,cust.getType());`